# findByName NullPointerException

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, codenameone

The following Codesnipplet throws an [nullpointerexception](/questions/tagged/nullpointerexception). It is thrown by the findByName-method. Looks like the couldn't find PlayerComponentGroupList but i don't know why.

How could i refer to the generated [componentgroup](/questions/tagged/componentgroup)?

```
protected void beforeMain(Form f) {
    super.beforeMain(f);
    try {
        findPlayerComponentGroup(f).addComponent(getItems("Player"));
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        throw new RuntimeException(ex.getMessage());
    }

}

private Container getItems(String order) throws IOException {
...
final Container rows = new ComponentGroup();
...
rows.setName("PlayerComponentGroupList");
    return rows;
}

protected void onMain_PlayerContainerButtonSortNameAction(Component c, ActionEvent event) {
    super.onMain_PlayerContainerButtonSortNameAction(c, event);
    try {
        findPlayerComponentGroup().removeComponent(findByName("PlayerComponentGroupList", Display.getInstance().getCurrent())));
...
}
```

Comment: Which method throws the exception? Why not run it in the debugger and see what returns null?

Comment: sorry, did not formulate this popper: findByName.... Fixed the Question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`findByName()` doesn't work that way. It will only work for components created by the GUI builder and is thus very fast (otherwise it would have to recursively search the component tree which is very slow).

You need to keep a pointer to the component and remove it.

Comment: could you add a short example please? THX

Comment: As Workaround i added an empty Container via GUI builder, on that i can use remove all and readd the needed components. Hope this is an acceptable solution?